# How to get all images from the phone storage into my application?

Tags: android, android-gallery

One activity of my Android application needs to show all the pictures from the phone including sd-card, camera pictures, downloads, etc. How can I perform this with the code? Whether through Intent or some other possible ways? (for instance in google+ application it shows all the pictures from the phone).

Comment: https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images

Answer (score 4):

You need to query the content database using the content resolver

```
String[] mProjection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

mCursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                               mProjection,
                               null,
                               null,
                               MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Using the mCursor above you can get the path to the images present on your external storage device.

You will probably require a `GridView` and the adapter to the `GridView` can use the cursor to get the images one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using the [`MediaStore.Images`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html) content provider. This will show all the images that appear in the Gallery app. However, it will not show hidden images, or images in folders that contain a `.nomedia` file. If you want to show those as well, you'll have to recursively scan the filesystem yourself (see [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) for that).

Comment: I don't think you need any. You should just try it and see if you get any security exceptions.

Comment: An example on this would be helpful. `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` only shows the images in external sd card directly not inside the folders. Please provide and example using recursively scan the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to open just the stock Android gallery application?

If you don't, you can always use this MediaStore class. It has all the info you need. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Comment: No, not if you're just reading from the sdcard. Writing to the sdcard would be another story, but in your case, you're not doing that, so you're ok.